# Перевод тектов естественного языка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задание, в котором даны два текста на русском и немецком языках. Нужно написать программу, которая будет создавать новый файл и выводить в него несколько предложений на русском с их переводом на немецкий?
Подскажите пожалуйста какие библиотеки и конструкции можно использовать для такой задачи?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А какие есть ограничения? Так то можно к `Google translate` обратиться за переводом. А можно нейросеть припахать. А можно тупо по одному слова через словарь перевести. Слишком много вариантов, как это можно сделать.

Comment: питон-библиотека к google translate называется googletrans. Были с ней некоторые нестыковки, не все версии работали, но советую начать с неё.

Comment: @AlexTitov Там ещё и ограничения на количество использований есть, но в целом да, лучше начать с чего-то такого

Comment: Вчитался в вопрос. "даны два текста на русском и немецком языках" -  т.е. это текст и его перевод? Если это так, то обычно  в таких переводах предложение соответствует предложению. Тогда в чем задача -  найти очередное предложение в обоих текстах с одинаковым по порядку номером и выводить их попарно?  И причём тут перевод как процесс, да еще через какую-то библиотеку?   Или вы ввиду имели что-то другое? Упорядочьте свои мысли и формулировку задачи.

Comment: @passant Хм, кстати, да. А я то думаю - какое-то сложное задание для начинающего дали ))

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать модуль googletrans для перевода текста и модуль os для работы с файлами.

Пример кода:

```
from googletrans import Translator
import os

# Создаем объект класса Translator
translator = Translator()

# Переводим предложения
translated1 = translator.translate("Привет, мир!", dest="de").text
translated2 = translator.translate("Как дела?", dest="de").text

# Создаем новый файл и открываем его для записи
with open("translations.txt", "w") as f:
    # Записываем переведенные предложения в файл
    f.write("Привет, мир! - " + translated1 + "\n")
    f.write("Как дела? - " + translated2 + "\n")
```

Comment: Возможно, некоторое время такое решение еще будет работать...